# Devise gem, rails 3, adding first record to db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

This may be my most stupid question yet:

I've implemented [this tutorial](http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/09/29/rails-authentication-with-devise-and-cancan-part-2-restful-resources-for-administrators/) on my Rails 3 app to get [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki) up and running with [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan). What is the right way to enter the first record in your development database, when only admins are allowed to enter a record and a null record isn't allowed? Do you just hack away some of the code to reduce permissions, then put it back again?

Update: to add to the answer, if you put this in seeds.db it works, even though there's no password field in the User table:

User.create(:email => 'me@mysite.com',:password => 'secret')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use db/seeds.rb to write the code for your admin record. And call rake db:seed to execute that. Make sure you check whether the initial records are already created, so that running rake db:seed won't duplicate the data.

Comment: optionally you can put it in a migration...that guarantees that you don't have to worry about duplicating the user. Some people bridle at putting this sort of thing in the migration, of course...